# How to send data via HTTP get in Java?

Tags: http, get, libcurl, multiplayer, cocos2d-x

So, I am going to connect to a servlet via an iphone and use HTTP. I am actually developing a multiplayer game and would like to know how I can send specific data to the iphone via HTTP get in java (doGet). I am using libcurl on the iphone (cocos2d-x).

Here is how my code is set up:

```
size_t write_data(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
    //do stuff with data        
}

//main or some init method
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
    char *data = "hi imma get=yeah";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://whatever.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data); 

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
              CCLOG("WELP BETTER DO SOMETHING ERROR");
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

So, what I would like to know is how I can use the response in the doGet method in java to send a string to that write_function defined above? As in, what do I do with response parameter in the doGet method?

For reference here is the doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException
 {
    System.out.println("GET METHOD CALLED");

 }
```

So, now what do I do with that response to pass some data to the write_function?

Thanks, for any and all input!!

Answer (score 1):

By using response's Writer, as shown below.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    // tell response what format your output is in, we select plain text here
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    // ask the response object for a Writer object
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        // and use it like you would use System.out.  Only, this stuff gets sent 
        //to the client
        out.println("GET METHOD CALLED");
    } finally {
        // housekeeping: ensure that the Writer is closed when you're ready.
        out.close();
    }
}
```

In some cases it's easier to use a Stream.  That's also possible **but you can never have both the Writer and the OutputStream open simultaneously**.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    // ask the response object for an OutputStream object
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    try {
        // output some stuff, here just the characters ABC
        os.write(new byte[]{65,66,67});
    } finally {            
        os.close();
    }

}
```

If you want to know more, there are loads of tutorials about servlets available on the web, including the [Servlet chapter of the official Java EE tutorial on oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

Comment: Alright thanks! write(String) will pretty much send any string written to the client. Does this mean that the void *data will contain the string I write using the PrintWriter or OutputStream?

Comment: @dgTheUser The data sent out by the servlet will be handed over to the write_data callback function in your example.  I see no `void *data` in your example and the `char *data` is never used.

Comment: the void *data is in the write_function and alright thank you!! Yeah the char *data is going to be used in the POST method, forgot to remove it.